# Replacing single quotation with double quotation of a string/object value

Tags: string, object, replace, double-quotes, single-quotes

i came acros a certain issue that refuses to solve itself, namely the transformation of single quotation string into double.

lets assume i do have the following string:

```
var str = "Hello World"
```

the output would be

```
'Hello World'
```

if it were to be part of object

```
var oObj = {"something": "Hello World"}
```

i would get

```
{'something': 'Hello World'}
```

and this is the main problem,

---

**Issue:** for the task ahead i need the object to have both (key-value pair) be in double quotations not in single ones.

The **key**: 'something' can be transformed via a (for var i in) loop with `"` + i + `"`;

The **value**: doesn't function like this, hence its perma `''` and doesn't react to many things.

---

**What i tried:**

```
var str = 'Hello World'
str = str.replace(/\'/gim, `"`)
'Hello World'
str = str.replace(`'`, `"`)
'Hello World'
str = str.substring(1, lastCharakter-1)
'Hello World'
```

splits that i tried dont work.

---

### Questions

1. How to transform, a single quotation string into double.
2. How to transform, a object that uses single quotation into double ?

Comment: Can you give an example of the task ahead that requires the double quotes? I am struggling to see why this is necessary ?

Comment: when sending a `PUT-request` via the low code plattform, `Simplifier` `(simplifier.io)`, or via `Postman`, if the `object` doesn't use double quotations it isn't recognized/accepted as a `object`